# How to call function without abi?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

Here is some random contract: 0x8055d0504666e2B6942BeB8D6014c964658Ca591

Pretend that the ABI was not uploaded on etherscan.io.

I want to run the function `supportsInterface(bytes4)` with data `0xa9059cbb` on that contract.

How do I do this with geth?

Answer (score 5):

Probably the easiest way is just to make your own ABI and then call it like you typically would. Here's an ABI for just this function:

```
[
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "bytes4"
            }
        ],
        "name": "supportsInterface",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "pure",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

I made some assumptions:

1. The function is `pure` (doesn't read from or write to storage).
2. The function returns a boolean.

You can easily hand-write ABI by looking at examples, but I made this one by just compiling the following contract in [Remix](http://remix.ethereum.org):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Foo {
    function supportsInterface(bytes4) pure public returns (bool);
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also construct the call data yourself... it should be the keccak256 hash of the function signature (`"supportsInterface(bytes4)"`) followed by a 32-byte (left-padded) version of the data (`0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a9059cbb`). But it's easier to just use the ABI. :-)